# How to name my variable class dynamicly in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Python: Why can't I modify the current scope within a function using locals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686715/python-why-cant-i-modify-the-current-scope-within-a-function-using-locals)
>   [How do you programmatically set an attribute in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285061/how-do-you-programmatically-set-an-attribute-in-python)

i know nammed dynamicly an varial in python with:

```
var = "my_var"
locals()[var] = "coucou"
print my_var
>>coucou
```

But i don't know how to make it on a variable class.
When i try:

```
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        var = 'ma_variable_dynamique'
        locals()[var] = 'toto'
        print ma_variable_dynamique
```

The exeception "NameError: global name 'ma_variable_dynamique' is not defined" is raised.

Example in php:

```
class Users extends Controller{
    public $models = array(‘User’);

    function login(){
        $this->User->validate();
    }

    //Call in contructor
    function loadModel(){
        foreach($this->models as $m){
            $_class = $m.’Model’;s
            $this->{$m} = new $_class();
        }
    }
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        var = 'ma_variable_dynamique'
        setattr(self, var, 'toto')
```

Answer (score 2):

This only explains why what you're doing doesn't work (not how to do it).

Documentation from http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals (**emphasis** mine):

> Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol
>   table. Free variables are returned by locals() when it is called in
>   function blocks, **but not in class blocks.**
>
> Note The contents of this dictionary **should not be modified**; changes
>   may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the
>   interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Use [setattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr).

```
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, "ma_variable_dynamique", "toto")
```